# DynamoDBTypeConvertedJson for an abstract class

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, abstract-class, dynamodb-mapper

Say my classes are structured as follows:

```
abstract class A {
}

class B extends A {
    String attOfB;
}

class C extends A {
    String attOfC;
}
```

Then, can my DynamoDB mapper class use A with `DynamoDBTypeConvertedJson`?

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName="ddbTable")
class ddbTableRecord {

    @DynamoDBTypeConvertedJson
    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private A a; 
}
```

Would this work, and if so, is it the right way to go about this? If this won't work, should I define a custom `DynamoDBTypeConverted` converter for class A that uses `instanceOf` to figure out what specific class the object belongs to?

Comment: If are going to put this much effort into you Amazon DynamoDB code, I recommend that you use the API considered best practice. That is, move from Java V1 to Java V2 and use the Enchanced Client for mapping. More information here -- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-dynamodb-enhanced.html